# Displaying how long til post expires

Tags: templating, entries

I'm trying to display how long til a certain post expires depending on a date/time field.

**Example**

> Expires in 13 days.

My field is currently displayed by doing `{{ entry.expiration }}`

I just don't know how I would just display the days remaining until this date.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `entry.expiration` is actually an object of type DateTime thus you'll have the full power of PHPs [DateDiff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) functionality

```
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

In Twig this is something like

```
{% set difference = now.diff(entry.expiration) %} 
{{ difference.format('%R%a days') }}
```

`now` should be the current date